# Trying to Combine toggleClass with slideDown to Reveal a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of buttons nested within divs, and am trying to reveal a second div when each button is clicked, like the grid buttons halfway down [this page](https://www.qualtrics.com/market-research/).

I'm attempting to use toggleClass to toggle the div between visible and hidden, which works fine. I can't seem to get the div to slide down once the button is clicked though. It works properly the second time the button is clicked, but only then.

Any suggestions?

```
$(function(){

$("#toprow #button1").click(function(){
$("#hiddentext1").toggleClass("showhiddentext1");
$("#hiddentext1").slideDown(500);
});

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bwoo5789/zhmowu39/

Comment: [___There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.___](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your text to toggle up / down on button press you can just use the `slideDown` and `slideUp` methods.  Toggling visibility isn't necessary as `slideDown` will do that for you.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhmowu39/66/)

```
$(function(){
    $("#toprow #button1").click(function(){     
    if($("#hiddentext1").is(':hidden')){
      $("#hiddentext1").slideDown(500);
    }else{
      $("#hiddentext1").slideUp(500);
    }    
  });  
});
```

Adding `overflow: hidden` to your div removes the jumpy effect when the `slideDown` completes.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!